# Using the result of main function in some other function embedded in a class in C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Suppose this is my code of main function:

`m` is the matrix which is the final result this function and `shaprDetect()` is the function of `class Vsharp`. Now, I want to use the `m` in this function `shaprDetect` to do some processing on it.

`void Vsharp::shaprDetect() { }`

Now tell me how to use that `m` in this function. 
All of them are part of the same project.

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[]) 
{
    m.at<float>(i,j) = exp(-RR/(2b2))(1-exp(-S2/(2c2)))*exp(-hypotenuse/gradscale); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is ill formed code. Or all parameters are global and m can be accessed from within shaprDetect(), or the program can not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant really use the return value from main. Because your program has exited. Assuming your shaprDetect method actually takes a parameter m do something like the below (but be aware that since you havent posted any details on what m is i am having to guess here)

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[]) 
{
    m.at<float>(i,j) = 
        exp(-RR/(2b2))(1-exp(-S2/(2c2)))*exp(-hypotenuse/gradscale); 
    //now call your shaprDetect function here

    Vsharp vs;
    vs.shaprDetect(m);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Basically m is an image matrix. it means instead of using the result of main function in the function shaprDetect of class Vsharp, we have to use function shaprDetect in the main function.

Comment: Thats basically it, yes. This real basic stuff though. Get yourself a good book on C++.